# curl command to fetch data of jira ticket using its ticket id

Tags: curl, jira, jira-rest-api

I need curl command which uses Jira ticket as an input and fetches the details of that particular ticket as response. I have a curl command for searching using username but I need it to use id instead of username

```
curl \
   -D- \
   -u charlie:charlie \
   -X GET \
   -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
   http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/search?jql=assignee=charlie
```

This is the command I found

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do withJava or Spring Boot, so next time tag it in the appropriate way. It will draw specific and more specialized attention. About your problem Atlasian documentation is pretty good, always refer to the documentation of the tool you are using: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-issue-search/#api-rest-api-3-search-get and here is the field reference data: https://support.atlassian.com/jira-software-cloud/docs/advanced-search-reference-jql-fields/ enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Use `/rest/api/2/issue/KEY-1` instead. KEY-1 is the ticket ID/key. You can also use issueId (number value).

I would recommend to start with the official Atlassian Jira REST API documentation:
https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/latest/

You request is described here:
https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/latest/#api/2/issue-getIssue